# How do i prepopulate a lookup user field on a custom object? (using URL hacking method)

Tags: urlhacking

I have a custom object "Service Timecard". One of the fields on the object is "Service Technician" which is a User Lookup field. I want to be able to prepopulate that field using URL hacking. I managed to override the "New Button" and this is what I have so far and it's not populating the User in the lookup field: `/a14/e?CF00N30000007Ceht&CF00N30000007Cehz{!$User.FirstName}{!$User.LastName}&CF00N30000007Cehz_lkid={!$User.Id}  Any ideas?` Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need forgot an '=' and also you only need to use {!user.Name}

Try

```
/a14/e?CF00N30000007Cehz={!User.Name}&CF00N30000007Cehz_lkid={!$User.Id}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: D'oh! For the life of me I couldn't see that. You know what, that fixed it. Thanks so much! :-)

Comment: Awesome, glad to help